# "You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>" even the link is inside the router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-dom

I am Learning the routing system in React . I checked everything in my code and it seems to be correct but I don't know why it does not work.

Versions:

```
"react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
"react": "^16.8.4",
```

**index.js**

We go to the  App.js from index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
import 'bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**App.js**

We implement BrowserRouter in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import Main from './components/MainComponent';

import './App.css';
import { DISHES } from './shared/dishes';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Main />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**MainComponent.js**

We define Routes in MainComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './HeaderComponent';
import Footer from './FooterComponent';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import Home from './HomeComponent';

import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';

class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dishes: DISHES
    };
  }

  render() {
    const HomePage = () => {
      return(
          <Home />
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/home' component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path='/menu' component={() => <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} />} />
          <Redirect to="/home" />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

**HeaderComponent.js**

NavBar, Nav in HeaderComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavbarToggler, Collapse, NavItem, Jumbotron } from 'reactstrap';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggleNav = this.toggleNav.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          isNavOpen: false
        };
      }

      toggleNav() {
        this.setState({
          isNavOpen: !this.state.isNavOpen
        });
      }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Navbar dark expand="md">
                    <div className="container">
                        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNav} />
                        <NavbarBrand className="mr-auto" href="/"><img src='assets/images/logo.png' height="30" width="41" alt='Ristorante Con Fusion' /></NavbarBrand>
                        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isNavOpen} navbar>
                            <Nav navbar>
                              <NavItem>
                                  <NavLink className="nav-link"  to='/home'><span className="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span> Home</NavLink>
                              </NavItem>
                              <NavItem>
                                  <NavLink className="nav-link" to='/aboutus'><span className="fa fa-info fa-lg"></span> About Us</NavLink>
                              </NavItem>
                              <NavItem>
                                  <NavLink className="nav-link"  to='/menu'><span className="fa fa-list fa-lg"></span> Menu</NavLink>
                              </NavItem>
                              <NavItem>
                                  <NavLink className="nav-link" to='/contactus'><span className="fa fa-address-card fa-lg"></span> Contact Us</NavLink>
                              </NavItem>
                            </Nav>
                        </Collapse>
                    </div>
                </Navbar>
                <Jumbotron>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row row-header">
                            <div className="col-12 col-sm-6">
                                <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                                <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Jumbotron>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Header;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Billy Chan! Nothing in this code looks apparently wrong. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a valid routing setup.... I always find debugging react-router a weird experience because it's always something super obvious that is also easy to overlook. Can you get a CodeSandbox or something up to poke around with? Some way to reproduce the issue?

Comment: This is my code.
It is weird. These codes seem work in the sandbox. However, it cannot work in my browser.
https://codesandbox.io/s/93jl773j1w